# How can I keep the thousands separator when exporting a Splunk Dashboard to PDF?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Is there a way to have the thousands separator in a table when exporting to pdf?

When I load the dashboard in Splunk, it shows the thousands separator in a table.

But when I export it to PDF, the thousands separator is not displayed.